# Overriding ".env" environment variable in dockerized React SPA at Docker container starting point

Tags: reactjs, docker, webpack, environment-variables, dotenv

I use "dotenv-webpack" plugin in my webpack build for React SPA.

In webpack.config:

```
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack')

const envFileName = env.local ? '.env.local' : isDevelopment ? '.env.dev' : '.env'

plugins: [
    // ...
    new Dotenv({
        systemvars: true,
        ignoreStub: true,
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, envFileName),
    }),
    // ...
]
```

In ".env" file there are some environment variables. ".env" is for production, but we have servers with distinct requirements, so, I need to override one variable in ".env" at Docker starting, depending on which server my image is started on.

It there a good way to override? For instance:

".env" is: `MY_VAR=xxx`
and, at starting container I want someting like this: `docker start -d -p 3000:3000 -e MY_VAR=yyy  my-container`

But looks like overriding does not work in this way.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out after some research, that "webpack-dotenv" uses static replacement for ENV usage across your SPA app code during compilation. It leverages DefinePlugin. So, ".env" is applied statically. As a consequence, we can't override ENV at runtime, so the only way is to pass an ARG to Docker at image building time and COPY server-specific config ".env" over a default one.